# How to use STANFORD PARSER from GATE

Tags: stanford-nlp, gate

How to use Stanford parser from GATE embedded (using GATE through Java code). I currently use GATE_Developer_7.0 on my machine; i know that there is plugin for Stanford Parser in GATE but don't know how to use it using java code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach we always recommend for GATE Embedded is to build up your pipeline using GATE Developer, test it out and get it debugged by processing sample documents in the GUI.  Once you're happy with the application, use "save application state" or "export for GATECloud.net" to produce a saved state that you can then load in your embedded code using the `PersistenceManager`.  This will automatically ensure that all the necessary plugins are loaded and is generally much simpler and less error-prone than trying to build up your pipeline by hand in your code.

The [BatchProcessApp example](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/javadoc/src-html/sheffield/examples/BatchProcessApp.html) on the GATE website shows how you can load a saved application with the PersistenceManager, essentially it's

```
Gate.init(); // always the first thing you do
CorpusController controller = (CorpusController)PersistenceManager
    .loadObjectFromFile(new File("/path/to/application.xgapp"));
Corpus corpus = Factory.newCorpus("myCorpus");
controller.setCorpus(corpus);
```

then for each document you want to process

```
Document doc = Factory.newDocument(....);
corpus.add(doc);
try {
  controller.execute();
  // code here to do stuff with the annotated document, e.g. extract
  // annotations/features
} finally {
  corpus.clear();
  Factory.deleteResource(doc);
}
```